# How would the educational system of a military magic institute be like?

Tags: magic, warfare, education

We're talking about a late-middle age civilization. Actually magic is a thing in this world (pretty powerful magic). This magic works almost as low reality manipulation using your life force (most of the times). Since some people have amazing magical affinity but low prana runes are almost always used and sometimes life force can be damaged if you don't take care of it. People have different talents (as the 7 types of intelligence) so a person who's bad in alchemy probably can be an excellent healer.

These are the magic types of my world:

- Healing (white magic, shielding)
- Curses (dark magic, spiritual damage)
- Reinforcement (for armors, shields and weapons)
- Alchemy (it's more like turning matter from the enviroment to create material in a magical circle, the best alchemists can create even weapons or arrows)
- Magical combat, the art of enhance your physical stats with mana
- Elemental bending (almost blood, but this is forbidden magic)

How can a medieval civilization create an educational system that allows the monarchy to use these mages in the battlefield?

Something I missed. Almost all are young (12-18 years old, when prana starts to activate)

Comment: How old are your mages, when they unlock said magic? If they are older, they act far more responsibly. If they are younger, you first have to teach them the principals of responsibility and have to help them to realise, just how dangerous the magic can be.

Comment: You're specifically looking for an education system that would appear in a military institute (like ROTC), as opposed to a general purpose education system which also trains doctors and scientists, right?

Comment: What is/are `prana`?

Comment: @dot_Sp0T *prana* is often used in the same place as *mana*. It is generally used to refer to magical energy of a being. So basically it's the magical capacity of whatever type of wizard you want to use.

Answer (score 6):

## The Apprentice System

The [apprentice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apprenticeship) system is great! Not only can the apprentices learn from a master, but these masters can also closely supervise their apprentices, teaching them about potential pitfalls and also preventing a lot of shenanigans a teenager with magic powers would get up to. 1-on-1 supervision would be needed

Even better, the masters and apprentices would be paid for by nobility, just like a minor knight (and their servants and their squires) would be. This system is very flexible, but lacks the centralization that you may want, but makes the mages ***very*** answerable to the nobility.

Having a "magic school" backed by some [guild](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guild) is just asking to compound the troubles of having magical teenagers. Want to keep a teenager out of trouble? ***Do not put them with other teenagers, but under close supervision of responsible adults.***

Answer (score 0):

## The School System

The actual educational system has a lot of advantages over old master-apprentice model.

1. The scale. One teacher gets to train 5, 10 or even 20 students, depending on the need of guidance.
2. Secondly, those students need overall education, too. If it is late-middle ages, we can't have people who are to wield so powerful magic being uneducated farmer's sons.
3. Community. Putting teenagers together is what creates bonds and friendships. We don't want those mages to be socially wild creatures who don't have any emotions and despise other human beings.
4. Standards. We can have procedures for finding the gifted children. Then, we can help them discover the kind of magic they are good at. And then we can teach them what they need to know.
5. Governance. Monarchy could have certain relations with the schools, probably founding them in exchange for the governance and material for battle mages, who trust and serve the kingdom.

## The Model

### The Preschool

Before the actual education, children could be examined on a global scale, perhaps having the obligation to visit the school at the age of 12.

### The Elementary School

One type for all the kinds of magic. Would teach basic safety, general knowledge and the basics of each kind of magic.

### The High School

Divided into separate departments for each kind of magic. Would require some entry exams. In deep understanding of that kind of magic, battle training etc.
After graduation, alumni are ready to work/fight/help society.

### The University

Mainly academic place. Used for research and discovery of spells (depending on your vision of magic). Those people usually don't go into battles or leave the academy at all.